Black specs in foam
I recently made a 10gal batch of ESB (which I have made many times). I took the following steps with this,

I fermented it in a 14gal stainless steel chapman pot for 2 weeks
Kegged it and tapped it to my kegerator for a week, but did not really drink much. It tasted okay (but not my best batch), not infected for sure though.
Took it off the kegerator and left it in the pantry (needed to ferment another beer in the kegerator for 2 weeks).
After 2 weeks of the beer sitting in the keg, I then put it back in the kegerator and tapped it.

The first couple pours I saw some black spots in the foam. I was able to pick them up with my finger and when I rubbed them with another finger they smeared black on my finger. I stopped seeing these black spots after about 3 glasses I poured out, but the beer seems to be tasting a little metallic to me now.
Anyone know what these spots may be or where I went wrong? Cant tell if they are from the keg (it was a used keg we bought), from the beer, or from the kegerator line (or tap?).

Sorry to hear about your ESB. Hopefully it clears up on it's own. I take a lot of shortcuts so would check into stuff that I don't regularly clean and see if gunk is building up on them. I never used to disassemble the gray and block ball connectors to clean them but one day I did and there was enough grime built up in there that I now take them apart to soak and then air dry after every use. Same with kegerator faucets and discos. I take those apart every couple kegs and soak the parts in oxi clean or PBW. Also check your o-rings on posts, valves and dip tubes and make sure they aren't deteriorating. I had a dip tube oring once that was all crumbly. I've also had gunk build up on my carbon filter so I change that every couple months too.
Not sure on the metallic taste, this is all just guesswork but could be lacto or some microbug got in there and maybe soured it up a bit. Could be aging ingrediets maybe? Using tap water?
The only other metallic taste I can think of may be from rusty parts. That's kind of hard to come by if all your metal is stainless. I have a chapman 7 gallon and it has produced good beer for me. I did see the bottom of someone's corny keg once that was all pitted to hell. I have no idea how it happened but the guy was putting beer in it.
Hope it helps. Good luck.

Thanks for the tips! I think you are right that I should take the ball locks apart and clean them. Not during I do regularly and it could be that. Do you take apart the tap itself as well?

Yeah the tap (faucet) will dissasemble (https://coloradobeer.org/tech-safety-posts/beer-faucet-cleaning-101/). Depending on the model, there will be one or two o-rings in there which could be deteriorated and causing black specs. You can get some small bottle brushes (https://www.amazon.com/Bottle-Cleaning-Brushes-Cleaner-Bottles/dp/B01N6QEINN) to help get stuff out of there but usually a good soak in PBW or similar will remove most build up.

Yeah I know HOW to take it apart. I just was more or less asking if I need to, or need to often?
I am new to the kegerator and not sure how often, or what all I need to clean on it. I have been running BLC through it after emptying a keg, but have not really been taking everything apart every time.

Gotcha. Yeah, running cleaner through it after every keg is a great way to keep the gunk down. I end up with gradual off-flavors over time and usually find some build up in the faucet. After a good soak, it seems to make quite a difference. Not sure if that's all in my head or what. Maybe let the cleaning slide for a few kegs and take things apart and see what you have. It seems like thick hazies will gum things up quicker than a WC IPAs so your mileage will vary.
